# Android Gradle Managed Devices - How to clear cached test results

Tags: android, gradle, android-espresso, gradle-managed-device

When running android espresso tests using [gradle managed devices](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices), how can you clear the test results that are cached if you want to force the test(s) to be re-ran?

Per https://developer.android.com/studio/test/gradle-managed-devices:
Caches test results and reruns only tests that are likely to provide different results

Comment: How did the cache work here? For me its either runs all tests or nothing if no changes. There is no in between.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like running ./gradlew clean works for this